# I cannot set the Global.asax properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mapping

I have added a new mapping to the Global.asax but It doesnt work properly.

My newly added link is "http://localhost:28759/Admin/ProductCategories"

and my new code in Global.asax is below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductCategories",
            "Admin/ProductCategories/{ID}", // Route name
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "ProductCategories", ID = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

but it seems to go to the general mapping, so it uses my main layout for my regular pages.

Since this is going to be an admin page, I dont want it to use the main layout. What am I doing wrong? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Is the problem incorrect layout or incorrect routing behavior?

Comment: this incorrect routing problem. and I added this before the default route

Comment: I think the layout problem is not related to the routing.

Comment: Agreed - The routing doesn't appear to be the issue. If you are getting the correct view, then definitely not. But routing has nothing to do with the layout page.

Comment: Your new route actually corresponds to the default rote `{controller}/{action}`, so are you sure that is makes sense to add such a route to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, add following section:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works but I think I should fix the Global.asax as well

Comment: You must remove the mapping you put in the global.asax file. The layout problem is not related to the routing. Just use the Christina's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separated layout for admin pages in ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml and define it in _ViewStart.cshtml file which should be created in ~/Areas/Admin/Views with following code

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```